# Get notification when iPod music is stopped

Tags: iphone, session, audio, ipod

I need to play background music in my app when no other (iPod) music is playing. I can determine it when initializing my audio session:

```
AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &varSize, &isPlaying);
```

But I want also to start my background music when user stops iPod player (pressing home button twice and pausing the music). How can I catch this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
    selector: @selector (onIPodPlayerPlaybackStateChanged:)
    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
    object: [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]];
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```